# What does SetGamePaused do internally?

Tags: unreal, unreal-5, pausing

I would like to implement changing game speed similar to RTS games (pause, 1x, 2x, 4x). For the faster times I can set bigger Time Dilation but for 0x time I would like to know if I can just use `SetGamePaused` and work around this function or implement another solution.

Which entities are stopped when you use `SetGamePaused`? From my testing, I found that `Actor` tick and timers are paused and you need to check “Tick even when paused” if you want to except an `Actor` from pausing, but is there anything else that is influenced?

And what is the difference between “Tick even when paused” and “Should perform full tick when paused” in `PlayerController`?